# Any way to process SQS messages asynchronously through FastAPI without BackgroundTasks?

Tags: python, fastapi, amazon-sqs

I've been looking around implementing background jobs using FastAPI. I have an API `/api/event` which validates the incoming request, and adds the events to be processed to a SQS queue and returns HTTP 202 (Accepted) back to the user if the event was accepted, HTTP 200 (Ok) otherwise.

With what I could read on the FastAPI documentation, the way to invoke a BackgroundTask is through another API.

Now what I want to do is, to keep a background task running (like cronjob) which polls for messages in SQS queue, processes those events and deletes them. (This part should not be dependant on an API call)
I want to do this preferably within the FastAPI project.

Reading the FastAPI docs didn't provide me with enough information to implement this. I also tried invoking a basic background job (prints datetime) using the `__init__.py` file but that takes control over the FastAPI process and the APIs become unusable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. Use celery for the asynchronous process of events (It does support it)
2. Use `async` and `await`  with your event processing function

As you mentioned, you want something in native FAST API then I think it should be best to use `async`, and await like below

```
async def get_event_done(event: list):
    # Do some asynchronous stuff to process the event
    return "event processed"
```

Now Let's utilize the above function with the python builtin library `asyncio`

```
futures = [get_event_done(event1), get_event_done(event2)]
event1_result,event_2_result = await asyncio.gather(*futures)

print("event 1 result", event1_result)
print("event 2 result", event2_result)
```

It is very easy and clever to gather results using `asyncio.gather`

**Further References:**

- [FAST API async, and await](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#async-and-await)
- [Build an async python service with FastAPI & SQLAlchemy](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-an-async-python-service-with-fastapi-sqlalchemy-196d8792fa08)